# Making all HTML elements with width 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make all elements in HTML tags to have 100% width. I did it manually from Dev tools. Is there is a way to do it for all HTML elements using CSS code?

I assigned body tag to a class and added property (`width:100%`), but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: *{width:100%;} , I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Add your `HTML` and `CSS` in question, better make a snippet using code snippet option.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this CSS snippet:

```
* { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: thanks. I tired it, but it didn't work for whole HTML page. It is working only for specific elements, or class, e.g. p, h1,...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try one of these, might do what you what you want

```
 * html{
width:100%
}
```

or

```
   html *{
width:100%
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tired it, but it didn't work for whole HTML page. It is working only for specific elements, or class, e.g. p, h1,...